# r.table not removing NA values from CSV file

Tags: r, string, csv, missing-data, read.table

I know this question is answered before but still i am not able to handle my problem.

I am using this code to read a CSV file and remove "NA" values from it.

**read.table("001.csv", header = T, na.strings = "NA")**

and output still contain "NA" values. Below is one of the output containing four different columns and 1454 is row name.

*1454    2006-12-24                   ,NA,NA,1

Comment: Try adding `strip.white=TRUE` in the `read.table`

Comment: If you use read.table without sep="," it might not read a comma-separated file correctly.

Comment: tried adding it but still no change in the output

Comment: The 'na.strings' parameter determines which values should _become_ true missing values. Notice that `NA` is not the same as `"NA"` , although that parameter setting above would make character "NA"'s into `NA`'s.

Comment: I tried both NA and "NA"

Comment: Saying you "tried" without complete code is not helpful. Nor is it clear what your input file looks like or what you expect. (for instance, there is no header in what you show.)

Comment: @ayushkumar If you can upload the file in dropbox or some other place, I can take a look

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you've already read in your file, you can keep all the rows with no NA values by using `na.omit()` or `complete.cases()`.

Use `na.omit()` with the following:

```
foo <- na.omit(foo)
```

For example, suppose you have the data.frame `foo`:

```
> foo
   a b  c
1  1 1 NA
2  2 2 NA
3  3 3  3
4  4 4  3
5 NA 5  3
6  6 6  3
```

The above code will give you the following:

```
> foo <- na.omit(foo)
> foo
  a b c
3 3 3 3
4 4 4 3
6 6 6 3
```

Alternatively, you could use `complete.cases()`:

```
foo <- foo[complete.cases(foo),]
```

Again, suppose you have the data.frame `foo`:

```
> foo
   a b  c
1  1 1 NA
2  2 2 NA
3  3 3  3
4  4 4  3
5 NA 5  3
6  6 6  3
```

The above code using `complete.cases()` will give you the following:

```
> foo <- foo[complete.cases(foo),]
> foo
  a b c
3 3 3 3
4 4 4 3
6 6 6 3
```

Comment: Not working tried both things ---- error for "Complete.cases"..........    d < d [complete.cases(d),]
Error in Ops.data.frame(d, d[complete.cases(d), ]) : 
  ‘<’ only defined for equally-sized data frames    ..................................   Also "FOO" is not working

Comment: Use the assignment operator `<-`, not `<`. Additionally, `foo` is an arbitrary variable; use whatever you named your data.frame in place of `foo` each time you see it.